# Volume on my touch bar is not showing up, only controls related to the application I am working on are showing up

Tags: macos, audio, touch-bar, sound-volume

My touch bar used to have options for brightness, volume, etc.

After my last os update, none of those are showing up. The only actions on my touch bar are for the application I am using. So if I'm using chrome, there's back, forward, refresh, new tab, but there's no volume control.

I saw that I need to go to settings -> sound -> select show volume in menu bar
but that is already selected for me.

Comment: Have you tried going to e.g. **System Preferences** > **Extensions** > **Touch Bar** > **Customize Control Strip…** and adding what's missing?

Comment: yes. The new buttons still disappear as soon as I go to chrome or whatever application I am using .

Comment: In e.g. **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard** is **[√] Show Control Strip** checked or unchecked?  What is **Touch Bars shows** set to? Regardless of how set try toggling them to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: If was set to 'App Controls', I switched it to expanded and that solved the problem. If you reply with this instruction I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard**, set **Touch Bar shows** to **Expanded Control Strip**.